# Specify maven plugin execution IDs in IntelliJ Run Configurations

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So I have this plugin defined in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>

      <!-- Executed when building for deployment. Shade plugin relocated lib classes to avoid multi-plugin conflicts. -->
      <execution>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              ...
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
          <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
          <outputDirectory>deployment</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <!-- Executed when building for testing. Shade plugin does not relocate to enable HotSwapping. -->
      <execution>
        <id>testing</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
          <outputDirectory>test</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

with two different executions - one for deployment and one for testing.

How do I create a Run Configuration in IntelliJ that allows me to specify the execution I want to run. The dialog does not offer that field anywhere and I could not figure out how to do it in the VM Options field as I don't know how to set that parameter from the command line (if that is even the proper way to do it).

I want to avoid using profiles in the pom because the pom is quite long and the only difference would be the relocation step in this one plugin. I would have a lot of unnecessary duplication using profiles...

Any ideas?

Comment: On Maven command line, you specify it as `maven-shade-plugin:shade@deployment`. BTW, I don't understand why you would have duplication if you use profiles? You could have one plugin configuration in one profile and one in the other, and the rest of the POM outside the profiles.

Comment: You can create two run/debug configuration where you specify the Maven goal to run in **Before launch** section, e.g. `shade@deployment`